# Change permissions via ftp in python

Tags: python, permissions, ftplib

I'm using python with `ftplib` to upload images to a folder on my raspberryPi located in /var/www.
Everything is working fine except that uploaded files have `600` permissions and I need `644` for them.

Which is the best way to do this? 
I'm searching for something like:

```
def ftp_store_avatar(name, image):
    ftp = ftp_connect()
    ftp.cwd("/img")
    file = open(image, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + name + ".jpg", file)     # send the file

    [command to set permissions to file]

    file.close()
    ftp.close()
```

Comment: If you have found a correct answer below, please be sure to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use sendcmd.

Here is a sample program that changes permissions via ftplib:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ftplib

filename = sys.argv[1]
ftp = ftplib.FTP('servername', 'username', 'password')
print ftp.sendcmd('SITE CHMOD 644 ' + filename)
ftp.quit()
```

Happy programming!

Answer (score 5):

I would use the SFTPClient in paramiko for this case:
http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html

You can connect, open the file, and change permissions like this:

```
import paramiko, stat

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(your_hostname,
               username=user,
               password=passwd)

sftp = client.open_sftp()
remote = sftp.file(remote_filename, 'w')
#remote.writes here
# Here, user has all permissions, group has read and execute, other has read
remote.chmod(stat.S_IRWXU | stats.S_IRGRP | stats.S_IXGRP
             | stats.IROTH)
```

The `chmod` method has the same semantics as `os.chmod`